# Image couldn't be seen in the Image View Area in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an image view in my view controller but weirdly I can't show my image inside of the imageview. It is located in the middle of the page or somewhere else in the other view controllers. My code of both image view and image picker are below.

[image: image view in the VC]

And this is the output. Arrow image doesn' t show in expected area:

[image: and this is the output. Arrow image doesn' t show in expected area]

```
profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "arrow_long_left")
profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
view.addSubview(profileImageView)   



func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

        if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        }

        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
            profileImageView.image = selectedImage
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func handleSelectProfileImageView() {

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            //picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        /*else if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
            picker.allowsEditing = true
            present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }*/
    }
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        print("canceled picker")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is off here:

```
profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
```

My guess is you want something more like this:

```
profileImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.trailingAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
profileImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.topAnchor).isActive = true
profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

If you want to fix the width and height to 150, you'll need to adjust a bit.  But, right now you're anchored to the centerX of the view, so its horizontally centered.  And anchored by the bottom to the top of the nameTextField - so of course its above the nameTextField

Comment: Thanks a lot dmorrow, it works great! But as you said when I try to arrange width and height with "profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true" code block, it didn't work. What should I do, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @gozdebal If you are going to sent the height/width of the image then you shouldn't set the trailing or bottom anchors, as that will over constrain the image.  It all depends on how you want your layout to respond to different sized devices